# Run as Spring Boot option not appearing in STS

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I imported a Working Spring Boot Maven Module Application into STS and the "Run as Spring Boot" option is not appearing. I did a Maven Update, Clean and Install. When the Install runs it completes some simple JUNIT tests. I'm sure its just a config problem somewhere. I know this isn't a lot to go on.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I'm not sure if it has anything to do with an updated version of the spring boot, I use JDK 17 for the spring boot applications

here's my solution:
go to the **Help** tab in Eclipse, --> navigate to "Eclipse Marketplace" --> type spring boot on the "find" bar, we should see Spring Tools 4 and the version release, --> install that

- then just go through the selections you want after you install, it may ask you to restart your IDE, then when you click 'run as' again, it should prompt you with "run as Spring application"

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are looking for Run As -> Spring Boot App while right-clicking on the Boot project in the Package Explorer or Project Explorer.
If the action isn't there open Launch Config wizard (Run As -> Run Configurations...). Check if "Spring Boot App" category is in the list on the left.

Comment: hi, I am facing same problem, and I checked that on left side on configuration page, it is showing "spring boot app" option, but when I try to run it from the package, I dont see that option.